# Accessing SIM info programmatically in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi, core-telephony

I am trying to build an app that needs access to Sim cards unique Identity for iOS devices. Is it possible to get the details like ICCID and IMSI of SIM cards using any Private APIs

Answer (score 1):

Look at this private [header](https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers/blob/master/CoreTelephony/CTSIMSupport.h).

Using these private functions you can get MCC, MNC and MSIN. [IMSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscriber_identity_module#International_mobile_subscriber_identity_.28IMSI.29) consists of those parts.
So you can construct IMSI.

As for ICCID - try to find suitable info in these [headers](https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers/tree/master/CoreTelephony).

Comment: Did you actually tried those or you just posted the first thing you found on the topic? Starting at iOS 7, for example, you can't access IMSI or any similar info without special entitlement.

Comment: Your link already contains the function to access IMSI - `CTSIMSupportCopyMobileSubscriberIdentity`. To use it on modern iOS versions you need to sign your app with `com.apple.coretelephony.Identity.get` entitlement set to true.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to add one more link with [entitlements](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CoreTelephony.framework).